# In Ruby, how can I apply an attr_accessor from a module that is being extended?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to modularize some Ruby code by organizing methods into separate modules. Originally I had something like this:

```
class Joe
  attr_accessor :name

  def self.arms
    2
  end

  def self.legs
    2
  end
end
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
class Joe
  extend Person
end

module Person
  include Name
  include Arms
  include Legs
end

module Name
  attr_accessor :name
end

module Arms
  def arms
    2
  end
end

module Legs
  def legs
    2
  end
end
```

However, the part that is not working is the `attr_accessor`. I've tried all different combinations of `include`/`extend`, `def self.included(base); base.extend` and I can't seem to find the right combination to make everything work together. How can I do this?

---

**Update:** I think the part that I left out was that each of the modules could potentially have both instance methods and class methods. So I currently have something like this:

```
class Joe
  include Person
end

module Person
  include Name::InstanceMethods
  include Arms::InstanceMethods
  include Legs::InstanceMethods

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend Name::ClassMethods
    base.extend Arms::ClassMethods
    base.extend Legs::ClassMethods
  end
end

module Name
  module ClassMethods; end

  module InstanceMethods
    attr_accessor :name
  end
end

module Arms
  module ClassMethods
    def arms
      2
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods; end
end

module Legs
  module ClassMethods
    def legs
      2
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods; end
end
```

While this works, it feels messy. It also feels like the `Person` module knows too much about the instance methods and the class methods. If I were to modify the `Name` module to remove the empty/unused `ClassMethods` module, I would also have to modify the `Person` class.

Comment: If I changed to `include` then the class methods would become instance methods.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 14):

[`include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-include) is defined in `Module`, and therefore can only be called on modules and classes (which are modules). It adds the constants, (instance) methods and (module) variables from the given module(s) to the receiver by calling [`append_features`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-append_features).

[`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-extend) on the other hand is defined in `Object`, i.e. it is not restricted to modules and classes. It adds the instance methods from the given module(s) to the receiver or, more precisely, to the receiver's singleton class.

Here's an example module with an instance method `hello`:

```
module Mod
  def hello
    "Hello from #{self.class} '#{self}'"
  end
end
```

If we `extend` an instance (as opposed to a class), then `hello` becomes an *instance method*:

```
str = 'abc'
str.extend(Mod)
str.hello
#=> "Hello from String 'abc'"
```

If we extend a class, then `hello` becomes a *class method*:

```
String.extend(Mod)
String.hello
#=> "Hello from Class 'String'"
```

This is because class methods are really just instance methods defined in the singleton class of a class.

That said, there are several options to define both, class and instance methods, by calling `extend` and / or `include`:

#### 1. `extend` and `include`

This is the most basic one, you could move `include Name` from Person into `Joe`:

```
module Person
  include Arms, Legs
end

class Joe
  extend Person
  include Name
end
```

#### 2. `extend` and `include` in superclass

Or you could make `Person` a class that `extend`s and `include`s the other modules and use it as `Joe`'s superclass:

```
class Person
  extend Arms, Legs
  include Name
end

class Joe < Person
end
```

The next options involve some Ruby magic - they use a callback to invoke `include` upon `extend` or vice versa:

#### 3. `include` from within `extended`

You could use the [`extended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-extended) callback to `include Name` from within `Person`:

```
module Person
  include Arms, Legs
  def self.extended(mod)
    mod.include(Name)
  end
end

class Joe
  extend Person
end
```

#### 4. `extend` from within `included`

Or you could `include Person` from within `Joe` and use the [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-included) callback to call `extend`:

```
module Person
  include Name
  def self.included(mod)
    mod.extend Arms, Legs
  end
end

class Joe
  include Person
end
```

3 and 4 look clean from within `Joe` but it might not be obvious (maybe even confusing?) that including or extending `Person` also defines class or instance methods.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely makes things easier to understand. I think the part that I left out that I'm still having trouble with is that the `Name` module contains both instance methods and class methods. I didn't think of `attr_accessor` as an instance method, but it only works when you use `include`. So then I'm left with trying to `include Name::InstanceMethods` and `mod.extend Name::ClassMethods` but it feels messy.

Comment: @Andrew you somehow have to `extend` the class methods and `include` the instance methods. Maybe there's a way to restructure your classes / modules.

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly get the functionality you want, you'll have to change `extend` to `include` and supply an `included` block in your module. That way you can have both instance and class methods defined in one module, simply `include` the module and organize your methods appropriately.

It might take a little bit of code re-organization but to help explain more, you can [read this article about how modules in Ruby work.](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/07/05/composition-in-ruby/)

If still unclear, you might want to look into [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval).